# autoreconf: automake failed / configure.ac: required file not found - but that file exists

Tags: bash, build, automake, autoreconf

I'm trying to build LALSuite. I have cloned its Git repository into a lalsuite folder. This folder contains a file called 00boot. According to the official instructions, I run ./00boot in bash while in the directory of the folder. I get the following error:

```
00boot: running autoreconf
configure.ac.7: error: required file 'src/LALFrameVCSInfo.c.in' not found
configure.ac.7: error: required file 'src/LALFrameVCSInfo.h.in' not found
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
!!! ./00boot: autoreconf failed
```

The contents of 00boot:

```
#!/bin/sh

## function to print error message and exit
fail () {
  echo "!!! $0: $1" >&2
  exit 1
}

## check script is being run from top-level source directory
test "$0" = "./00boot" || fail "must be run from top-level source directory"

## remove M4 cache files
rm -rf autom4te.cache/
rm -f aclocal.m4

# FIXME: autoreconf from Ubuntu 9.10 (and probably also from recent
# Debian versions) automatically run libtoolize with the --copy option
# therefore over writing the supplied libtool scripts with system
# version. This can lead to unexpected build failures therefore to work
# round this "feature" we set the LIBTOOLIZE enviroment variable to
# point to the the true executable which bypasses the running of
# libtoolize, this will not effect the vast majority of users and those
# it will effect will know how to run libtoolize, if required.

## run autoreconf
AUTORECONF=${AUTORECONF:-"autoreconf"}
echo "00boot: running ${AUTORECONF}"
LIBTOOLIZE=true ${AUTORECONF} || fail "${AUTORECONF} failed"

echo "
==================================================
00boot has been run successfully.
Now run './configure' with appropriate options
to configure LALSuite.
==================================================
"
```

The thing is that both of the files in question exist in lalsuite/lalframe/src. Why does the console say that they do not exist/cannot find them and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which directory are you running the `autoreconf` command from?

Comment: From lalsuite, the folder with 00boot. Inside lalsuite there is lalframe which contains the two files in question.

Comment: Try running it from the root of the project directory instead.

Comment: `autoreconf.ac` content is needed obviously

Comment: 00boot is lower in hierarchy so I don't see why it doesn't locate the two files. YSC, I'm not sure what you mean by that.